# setdefault() takes no keyword arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7, setdefault

I have the following code snippet:

```
mirna2age = {}
for i in agesdb:
    mirna2age.setdefault(i[0],default=[]).append(i[1])
```

However, Python returns

```
TypeError: setdefault() takes no keyword arguments
```

I am unsure why. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set default should be used like:

```
mydict.setdefault(key, defaultvalue)
```

Don't use kwargs, just provide teh default as the second argument.

Answer (score 2):

The arguments are positional so change the call to:

```
    mirna2age.setdefault(i[0], []).append(i[1])
```

the message is telling you this function doesn't define named arguments